# How can I reduce the number of queries laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hello friends I implemented the comment system in the Laravel project and everything was ok, but when the admin responds to user comments, a query for the comment is executed by the admin, even those comments that the admin did not respond.

```
public function admin()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'parent_id','id');
    }
```

```
@forelse($article->getCommentActive() as $comment)
            
            @foreach($comment->admin as $admin)
                {{--something--}}
            @endforeach
@empty
   
@endforelse
```

controller

```
   public function show(Article $article,Request $request)
    {
       
         $article->checked($request);

       
         $categories=Category::get()->pluck('name');

       
         $suggestedArticles=$this->suggestedArticles($article);

        return view('articles.singleArticle',compact('article','categories','suggestedArticles'));
    }
```

How can I reduce the number of queries?

Comment: can you update answer with controller function code that sending data to the view?

Comment: Look at eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: how you get `$comment` variable to view?  is it in this `compact('article','categories','suggestedArticles')` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I know this, but my problem is different, I do not know what to do, I will be involved for 2 days ☹

Comment: @Viduranga Check now

Comment: Can we see the code for `->getCommentActive()` as well ?

Comment: in `>getCommentActive()` function you can eager load admins when load comments. eg: $comments->with('admin')->get().  make sure you have reverse relationship in Comment model.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier ` public function getCommentActive()
    {
        return $this->comments()->where([
            ['status',1],
    ])->get();
    }
`

Comment: You can add `$this->comments()->with('admin')->where...` to eager load the admin

Comment: @Viduranga Wow, thank you very much bro, just one more thing, I installed the debugger package and now it has 12 queries and 33 models created on one page. Should it be less or normal?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnierThat's right, that's my problem